# My Fonts are mostly hidden in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, fonts

I'm stuck - I used Suitcase Fusion 2 to try and manage a large body of shareware fonts I bought, but I hated it and uninstalled. Now when I go to the Fonts control panel in Windows 7, the vast majority of my fonts are hidden. Is there a way to unhide them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not too sure if the other answers have any experience with Suitcase Fusion, but I've been using that software for beaucoup years, and I've learnt early in the game that :

If you manage your fonts using Suitcase Fusion, it stores the fonts in its own secret directory, and only adds it to the Windows fonts when you ACTIVATE those fonts.

Now, once you've uninstalled Suitcase Fusion, your fonts (as you said, hidden) cannot be found in Windows fonts, and have never been in there to start with.

I have not used Windows Suitcase Fusion for quite awhile now (having switched to a Mac for design work), and if I remember correctly, the fonts you have managed with Suitcase Fusion can be found in C:\Documents And Settings[username]\Application Data\Extensis\Suitcase... something something.

Comment: I've looked at the Suitcase Fusion 2 User Guide, and I believe your answer is the right one and mine is wrong.

Comment: No worries mate, I get things wrong more often than you do I'm sure! :)

Comment: Not according to your comments that I see on SU ...

Comment: i'm just lucky. :P

Comment: this is exactly right, that's where they put them. However, the problem is now that I've uninstalled that, and copied all the files back into my fonts directory, they still don't show up in the Windows > Font control panel.

Comment: what are the font extensions? otf? ttf? did you try adding them manually by using File > Install New Font in XP's Font cpanel?

Comment: it's not adding... it's uninstalling them that's the problem. They were there since I uninstalled Fusion, but they're still there.

Comment: Huh? Erm... right-click > delete??

Comment: Do you think you can post a screenshot of what's happening, so we can help you? At this moment I'm kinda lost as to what you really want to do...

Answer (score 1):

Here's the thing: you want Suitcase so that you don't need to install fonts. With Suitcase, you can simply switch fonts on/ off without ever installing them.

However, upon switching on a font, Windows 7 will create a SHORTCUT to that font in its own font folder. This is done by Windows 7's Font Cache Service. It will remain there even if you switch off the font in Suitcase, and enables you to use the font even if you switch it off in Suitcase. If you don't use the font for some time, it will automatically be removed.

Once you uninstall Suitcase, Windows does not know where the actual font was anymore so the shortcut will be removed/ hidden. This is only logical since the font was never installed. If you still want to use it without Suitcase, you'll simply need to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see these hidden fonts with File / Install new font in the Fonts control panel ?
If yes, just reinstall them.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to see them - that's the problem, they're hidden. They're there when I look at the command line listing of the directory.

Answer (score -1):

right click on the hidden font(s), select **Show**.

of course you can select the lot and 'Show' them in one go.